# Como hacer una select search simple

Tags: html5

El codigo para crear el select es normal
[image: Select creado de manera norma]

Este es el script que se agreago ademas de lacondicion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si usas JQuery, podrías utilizar Select2, este plugin te permite utilizar búsquedas, carga de datos entre otras cosas. [Select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)

Answer (score 1):

Has probado [select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)? Es facil de utilizar y no arruina la forma en la que tus datos se muestran, solo debes referenciar tu select en base a su ID y adjuntar el codigo luego de que tus datos se carguen.

Ejemplo en la web(luego de que la pagina se cargue):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#descriptionItem').select2();
 });
```

Aplicandolo a tu codigo(suponiendo que asi sea):

```
//Tu codigo que asigna los valores al select(creeria que lo haces con un for each)
//luego de asignar todos los valores conviertes tu select normal a un select tipo select2
$('#descriptionItem').select2();
```

Si necesitas mas referencias, puedes consultarlas en su web.

Ahora bien, si no quieres utilizar nada de eso, te recomiendo visites este hilo [Filter options of select box using input box value](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140420/filter-options-of-select-box-using-input-box-value).

Saludos

Comment: Hola Francisco, agradezco tu respuesta, pero ya he integrado la parte de script que me dijiste en mi codigo html haciendo referencia al id, la respuesta a esto dice que "select2 not is a function"

Comment: Hola Fernanda, en ese caso puede ser por 2 cosas. La primera, no tienes referenciada la libreria jquery en tu pagina, para resolver eso agrega esto: "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>" en el header de tu pagina o la segunda es porque el control select no se a cargado, para tal motivo prueba hacer esto: if ($("#descriptionItem").length > 0) $("#descriptionItem").select2(); Disculpa el formato del comentario, pero estoy desde la app movil y mo me deja colocar formato para codigos. Saludos

Comment: La condicion soluciono uno de los errores ya no marca niniguno,pero no me aparece el buscador en mi select :/

Comment: Podrias colocar tu codigo para ayudarte mejor